# photo.SE chatroom

Tags: discussion

The current chatroom is located here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photographic-memories

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/chat-now-in-public-beta/ for details about the chat.

Comment: Thanks @che. Sure hope we can get that over here soon; it's pretty buried right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a chatroom without Question Feeds that jrista created:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photographic-memories

Comment: Do you think it would be good to organise a regular "meet the moderators" or even just a regular time to get more people in there for a good old chat?

Comment: @Rowland - yes!